# Tree View in e4 Rcp application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have worked in eclipse 3.x rcp development. But its appearance has been not so good. So when e4 came, it looked very amazing and good looking. I started working on e4 application. Iam just new to e4 rcp application development. I need to know how can we provide the treeview or tableview in e4 rcp. How can we provide data to the view by content provider and label by label provider. Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse4 application can still use JFace table and tree viewers.  See how the e4.demo.contacts view uses TableViewer in its [ListView](http://git.eclipse.org/c/e4/eclipse.platform.ui.e4.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.e4.demo.contacts/src/org/eclipse/e4/demo/contacts/views/ListView.java) implementation.